# Children book/picture book template

Tags: packages, templates, document-classes, book-design, documentclass-writing

I got inspired by the book "Newtonian Physics for Babies" and other books by Chris Ferrie. So I wanted to gift a children book to someone in my family. The book will be a first encounter  with math and physics, something like "My First Book about Mathematics and Physics".

The problem is that I can't seem to find a good template for this. I want the pages to be A5 size so that I can print 4 pages (2 pages on one side) on an A4 paper. I tried `\documentclass[a5paper,13pt]{book}`, but this doesn't seem right. Maybe the `scrbook` class? I would also appreciate input on which font I should use. I am also open to write a new documentclass, although I have very little experience in doing so.

Summary: I want help to find/create a template for children book/picture book.

Comment: I use Overleaf and pdfLaTeX as compiler if that is relevant.

Comment: To get 4 pages on one side I would recommend a two step process: First create your document with normal pages, then use [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) to create a document with 4 pages (1st document) on one side in  the 2nd document.

Comment: @knut: I would recommend a single step without `pdfpages`  to avoid unwanted scaling effects. If the original pages are A4 and we import them from other A4 host pages where 2 original pages are  placed in a host page with `pdfpages` then the original pages will be scaled down. It is not good. :-) If we are sure the book will be printed in A5, then write it in A5 from the beginning.

Comment: The standard type size options are 10pt, 11pt and 12pt but the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) has options 14pt and upwards. In any event, `memoir` provides many facilities for styling the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most babies don't need table of contents, cross references, as well as bibliography, I think using slides (such as `beamer` class) is more appropriate.

If features provided by `beamer` are too advanced for the babies, we can write the slides manually with drawing packages, such as PSTricks, TikZ, Asymptote, MetaPost, etc.

Here is an example with PSTricks:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newenvironment{slide}[1][]{\pspicture[#1](200mm,138mm)}{\endpspicture}
\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\rput[b](100mm,10mm){\parbox{180mm}{\centering\fontsize{25pt}{35pt}\selectfont #1}}}
\begin{document}
\slide[showgrid]
\pscircle[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](100mm,80mm){15mm}
\cc{This is a ball on a table.}
\endslide
\slide
\pscircle[fillcolor=red,fillstyle=solid](100mm,80mm){15mm}
\psline[linewidth=10pt]{->}(100mm,80mm)(100mm,40mm)
\uput{5mm}[r](100mm,50mm){\fontsize{25pt}{35pt}$\vec{F}=G\,\frac{m M}{r^3}\,\hat{r}$}
\cc{Gravitational force acting on the ball. Ouch Charlie! That really hurts!}
\endslide
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would you go about adjusting the page size?

Comment: @Vebjorn: Change the relevant parts: `border` of the `standalone`, `\pspicture()`, and `\cc`.